# Google cloud error -83104 (Internal server error) when using speech-to-text

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I am trying to transcribe a long mp3 file (45 mins long).
Here are the details of my configuration.

[image]

When using the 'video' model, it worked without a problem. But for some reason the 'long' model has a problem.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The error code **"Internal server error -83104"** indicates that there's an issue on **Google Cloud's server side**. Internal server errors are typically temporary and should be resolved by the service provider.

Internal server errors are often transient, so try re-running your Speech-to-Text operation after some time. It's possible that the issue will be resolved.